# Reading between the lines

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, phrase-choice

What are the Italian equivalents of the English expression "reading between the lines"? One could say "intravedere le vere motivazioni o i veri sentimenti di qualcuno" but I'm not sure if there are better ways to say it. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quite simply we say *[leggere tra le righe](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/R/riga.shtml)*.

> **leggere tra le righe**
>
> Riuscire a capire anche quello che non viene chiaramente espresso oppure deliberatamente taciuto, riferito a uno scritto, a un discorso e simili.

Comment: This is, I would say, one of the rare occasions in which there is a literal translation between an Italian saying and its English equivalent. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, not that rare really, they all seem to pop up in here

Answer (score 1):

Yes... The meaning is *Leggere tra le righe* but actually it is used in so many ways... For example:

You are having an argument with your girlfriend, and she says: *"Devi anche saper leggere tra le righe! Una donna non dice sempre tutto!"*

In this case your Italian GF wants you to understand something that she WANTS but she doesn't want to tell you...

Sometimes it is used when someone is disappointed!